# Key for browser apps (with referers) is not working

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get data from this [Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=mykey) 
and I take

```
    { "debug_info" : [],
      "html_attributions" : [],
      "results" : [],
      "status" :"REQUEST_DENIED }
```

I put the key for browser app from api console.
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console
2. Login with your google account
3. From left panel, go to Services
4. From the list on new page, turn on "Google Maps API v3" and **"Places API"**
5. From left panel, go to API Access
6. In the new page, look for a section named "Simple API Access"
7. In that section, you will find "Key for browser apps (with referers)" and below that, an API Key.
8. Copy the API key value.
9. In your request, replace the "mykey" with the actual key value copied

(You may need to wait few minutes to have the effect of the change)

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_api_key.asp) page has some screenshots.

Comment: Did you do the "waiting" part also?

Comment: Check this, your url with my key. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAHl97th30ak_tskKbKfJWRtuSF9fMAeX8

Comment: I waited for a long.I retry... 
No way the key can not apply;I checked your url ,that's i want to display but i can't....